# MSP430: Error initializing emulator: No USB FET was found MacOs

Tags: macos, microcontroller, msp430, texas-instruments, code-composer

I have mabook air m1 with macOS Ventura, so i connect eZ430-F2013 to my laptop using special usb hub, and my laptop finds it, but when i try to dump code into the Ez430-F2013 using Code Composer Studio it returns me "MSP430: Error initializing emulator: No USB FET was found", what should i do?

ps: thats what the system_profiler SPUSBDataType returns me:

```
USB:

    USB 3.1 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8103USBXHCI

        USB2.0 HUB:

          Product ID: 0x0101
          Vendor ID: 0x1a40  (TERMINUS TECHNOLOGY INC.)
          Version: 1.00
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
          Location ID: 0x00100000 / 1
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

            MXT USB Device:

              Product ID: 0x8816
              Vendor ID: 0xaaaa
              Version: 13.08
              Serial Number: 150101v01
              Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
              Manufacturer: MXTronics
              Location ID: 0x00120000 / 2
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 100
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

            MSP-FET430UIF JTAG Tool:

              Product ID: 0xf430
              Vendor ID: 0x0451  (Texas Instruments)
              Version: 1.01
              Serial Number: TUSB341017361696CE41FF07
              Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
              Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
              Location ID: 0x00110000 / 3
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

    USB 3.1 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8103USBXHCI
```

I tried

```
#include <msp430f2013.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

but that returned me error, in theory it should dump compiled code into my MCU and do nothing.

Comment: Do you have a log or more extensive error message that indicates what Code Composer is doing in the background?

Comment: how can i get it?